# Accessing request object in an initializer in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2

How can I access the `request` object in a rails initializer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible.

A request object is generated on each request sent to the server, thus it does not exist when you initialize your rails application.

I'd be surprised to see an answer which states otherwise, but that doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: That makes sense. Silly me.

Answer (score 0):

I jumped on a hackhands session and got the answer to this question.

In your application.rb file, you can define variables and set their values

```
config.heroku_worker_count = 0
```

You can then access and manipulate the variable app wide, say in a model, by using this syntax:

```
Rails.application.config.heroku_worker_count = 1
```

This persists values which is why I wanted an object. However, as the accepted answer states, this isn't viable using a call like:

```
config.heroku_worker_count = MyModel.new
```